# What kinds of sites/apps is Heroku best suited for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, hosting

Recently I have been dabbling in Ruby on Rails by learning it through Michael Hartl's tutorial and various other resources on the net. I'm quite impressed with it and have a number of ideas for applications I want to write with it.

Heroku seems like a really nice option for deploying these applications - it's smooth and extremely easy to set up, which is great. Something that I'm not clear on, however, is the type of projects Heroku is best suited for. This might seem like a subjective question, but keep in mind that I am asking from an entirely technical aspect (for instance, "Heroku is most used for X because of Y"), trying to figure out which option would work best given the type of projects I'm interested in.

With that said, I have three basic types of applications I'd like to write:

- A personal site with a blog front page and several content pages
- A community site that acts as a repository for Illustrator ".ai" files with forums and possibly a wiki
- An image host with forums

For each of these projects, which would be best: Heroku, a traditional host with RoR support, or a different cloud host with RoR support?

Answer (score 6):

Heroku is designed for any kind of webapp really. It is designed to scale well depending of your needs.

If you want to host user files you will have to use an outside service like amazon S3, because heroku is not designed to upload files directly in the application. Which is a good practice.

http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-size

http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3

http://aws.amazon.com/s3/